# 2 codecs in one filter module for logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I would like to ask question about filter plugin

I am using logstash 5.0.0 alpha4

I am in a situation where I have to set multiline codec and plain codec in single file module.
This seems to not work since logstash is not recognizing the plain codec.

```
  file {
    path => ["/var/log/logstash/data/log/g_02/*/always/*"]
    start_position => "beginning"

    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "----------------------\+|Present Rot \[360deg\]|Total   Rot \[360deg\] "
      negate  => false
      what    => previous
    }

    codec => plain {
      charset => "ISO-8859-1"
    }
```

Is my configuration wrong?

Comment: can you not set the charset in the multiline codec?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not possible. There is an open issue about this: https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1723